# Draw a curved path using [out, in]

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could you help to draw a curved path joining the (0,3)  and (0,4)? I find the draw command with in and out options hard even after reading about it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw[decoration={aspect=.23, segment length=2.0285mm, amplitude=4.16mm,coil},decorate] (0,5.2) -- (0,4); 

  \draw(0,5.2)--(0,6)--(-1.4,6);
  \draw(-1.5,6.5)--(-2,6)--(-3,6)--(-3,5);
  \draw[fill=black](-3,5) circle(3pt);
  \draw[fill=black](-3,4) circle(3pt);

  \draw(-3,4)--(-3,3)--(0,3);

  \draw  (0,3) % Draws a line
  to [out=-10,in=-40] (.24,3.1125)
  to [out=10,in=70] (.641,3.6) 
  to [out=-90,in=30] (0,4); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try something like this to draw curve between `(0,3)` and `(0,4)`.

```
  \draw (0,3) to[out=30,in=210,looseness=2] (0,4);
```

Alternate way is to use `controls`

```
  \draw (0,3) ..controls (1,3.25) and (-1,3.75).. (0,4);
```

Result:

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
  \draw[decoration={aspect=.23, segment length=2.0285mm, amplitude=4.16mm,coil},decorate] (0,5.2) -- (0,4); 
  \draw(0,5.2)--(0,6)--(-1.4,6);
  \draw(-1.5,6.5)--(-2,6)--(-3,6)--(-3,5);
  \draw[fill=black](-3,5) circle(3pt);
  \draw[fill=black](-3,4) circle(3pt);

  \draw(-3,4)--(-3,3)--(0,3);
   \draw (0,3) ..controls (1,3.25) and (-1,3.75).. (0,4);
\node[below] at (0,3) {With \texttt{controls}};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
  \draw[decoration={aspect=.23, segment length=2.0285mm, amplitude=4.16mm,coil},decorate] (0,5.2) -- (0,4); 
  \draw(0,5.2)--(0,6)--(-1.4,6);
  \draw(-1.5,6.5)--(-2,6)--(-3,6)--(-3,5);
  \draw[fill=black](-3,5) circle(3pt);
  \draw[fill=black](-3,4) circle(3pt);

  \draw(-3,4)--(-3,3)--(0,3);

  \draw (0,3) to[out=30,in=210,looseness=2] (0,4);
\node[below] at (0,3) {With \texttt{to}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```